# Referencing generic type parameter shadowed by abstract type member

Tags: scala, generics, type-members

Is there a way to reference a generic type parameter that is shadowed by an abstract type member of the same name?

Suppose we have a trait and extending class:

```
trait Foo {
    type T
    var get: T = _
}

class Bar[X] extends Foo {
    override type T = X //We can set the type member by referencing the generic parameter X
}

class Baz[T] extends Foo {
    override type T = ??? //How can we reference the generic parameter T here?
}
```

Obviously it's usually not a big deal to just name the generic parameter different than the type member, but this isn't always the best option (for example, when using an external library).  Is there a way to reference the shadowed generic parameter?  Where in the Scala spec is this interaction between type members and generic parameters delineated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without overriding the trait's abstract member, the type `T` will always refer to the inherited type member, and not the generic parameter.  This is a known issue, filed as [SI-8421](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8421).  From the proposed fix, it is explained why this is a bug:

> When binding a name to a symbol, we search up through the context
>   chain. At each step, we first look in the current scope. If that
>   fails, we look for members of the prefix of the closest enclosing
>   context associated with a `Template` or `PackageDef`.
>
> However, this means we will look for an inherited type member before
>   finding an eponymous class type parameter, which is in the scope of an
>   enclosing context two levels out.

So maybe after that issue is resolved (marked for 2.12.0-M2), it will become possible to reference the shadowed type, even if the abstract type member is overriden.